# c function declaration explanation on argument with type "void(*fcn)(void*)"

Tags: c++, c, function, arguments

I encountered the following line as a C function declaration. I'm confused by the type of the first argument passed in. Can anyone explain how to understand the type of the first argument?

```
int clone(void (*fcn) (void *) , void *arg, void *stack)
```

Comment: As you might guess by the name, it's a function.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: Ah. So it's a pointer to function whose return type is void and argument type is a pointer to void?

Comment: @James: that is correct.

Comment: Thank you all.You guys are fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void (*fcn) (void *)
```

Read the type from inside out: `fcn` is a pointer to a function, that function takes a `void *` parameter and returns nothing (`void`).

Answer (score 3):

Use ["Spiral Rule"](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) :

```
      +------+
      | +--+ |
      | ^  | |
void (*fcn ) (void *)
  ^   ^    | |
  |   +----+ |
  +----------+
```

So,

- `fcn` is a pointer to
- a function having `void *` as an argument
- returning `void` (nothing)

Answer (score 1):

After a few editing (to remove the names of variables) [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com) gave the [answer](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+clone%28void+%28%2a%29+%28void+%2a%29%2C+void+%2a%2C+void+%2a%29):

> declare clone as function (pointer to function (pointer to void) returning void, pointer to void, pointer to void) returning int

Or, you can test only the first argument and get it's type: pointer to function of pointer to void, returning void.